# How do you draw multiple consequtive segments with one click per node with inkscapes node editor?

Tags: inkscape

### Background

When using the pen tool to create a new path the workflow is as follows:

1. Place node
2. Place second node and create segment between 1-2
3. Repeat

### Problem description

Often I want to create many connected segments but repeating this workflow has two issues. If I accidentally doubleclick (click too fast), it will create a new node instead of creating a segment from the node I just placed. If I accidentally move my mouse slightly this can also happen because I may miss the previous node.

### Question

Is there any modifier or mode switch so that I may create multiple connected segments with one click per node instead of two clicks per all non-endpoint nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: icon] "Draw Bezier curves and straight lines"

The drafting pen tool allows that, click to set the location, drag to set the curvature, then release the mouse.

One click per node.